# No Third Party script is loading, why?

Tags: 2013

SharePoint 2013, added a custom application page and trying to add third party scripts to it but non works, so far i tried select2 and typeahead it through errors,

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

and .aspx page then,

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link href="jquery.select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fling.css" />
    <script src="/_layouts/15/jQuery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fling.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

and,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
});
```

which is in `fling.js` file...

I am also trying to add it in `page-init`

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("jQuery"))
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "/_layouts/15/jQuery/jquery.min.js");

    if (!cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("jQuery.Select2"))
    {
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery.Select2", "/_layouts/OwnSolutionFolder/jquery.select2.js");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with this,

```
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery.Select2", "/_layouts/15/OwnSolutionFolder/jquery.select2.js");
```

Still don't know why it doesn't work when i add it to .aspx page

Answer (score 1):

To include in `.aspx` page, you can use following tag.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Name="~SiteCollectionLayouts/<Path To Folder inside layouts folder>/jquery-1.11.1.js" runat="server"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

I hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The likely culprit are publishing pages (and some other as well), where `$` is sometimes used as a function name by Sharepoint itself.
An easy solution is to use [jQuery's no-conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
jQuery.noConflict(); //Right after jQuery is loaded
```

And then wrap all your own script files to use `$` for jQuery instead:

```
(function ($) {
    //Your script goes here, $ is now jQuery in this scope
} (jQuery));
```